# Removing artifacts from microscopy images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, artifacts

First things first: I am a complete programming noob and I have tried to tackle the problem with cv2 in Python.
I am trying to process images from  Light Sheet Microscopy. As you can see there are those white stains, which are artefacts and I don't know how to get rid of them. [corpus delicti](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtCOo.png)

- Removing the noise was easy to accomplish since I had some "bare" images with only the noise. A median filter also does its job well.
- Removing those white stains is really bothering me - they represent the pixels brighter than 59 (off 255). [pixels brighter then 58 marked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIbFE.jpg)
  [Distribution of pixel values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1wqK.png)
- After removing the white stains I hope to be able to just enhance the contrast of the image by using either histogram stretching or histogram equalization.

Does anyone have an idea how I could approach this problem?

Comment: Did you try `plt.imshow(image, vmin=0, vmax=59)`?

Comment: Can you share any code you may already have?

Comment: @CrisLuengo : I just tried it - unfortunatly it didn't do anything at all to the image. I've tried it like this: import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_image = cv2.imread('BLAHBLAH.tiff')

plt.imshow(input_image, vmin=0, vmax=59)

Comment: @YakovDan I've tried to get rid of the noise without a median filter and to enhance the contrast by streching the histogram. Unfortunatly I can't post the code in this section.